# Is there a .NET library to Normalize PCM WAV

Tags: c#, silverlight, audio, normalization

I want to normalize PCM WAV files from client side(Silverlight). I am using ASP.NET MVC on the server side. And I found a C program here

https://neon1.net/prog/normalizer.html
Does anyone know that if there are similar C# libraries that I can use directly?

Comment: There are several questions about C# audio libraries here. One of those can surely do it. NAudio even has a compressor:  http://naudio.codeplex.com/

Comment: Thanks for that. I looked at NAudio. But I mean if there is a library I can call immediately like: Lib.Normalize(soundfile, ..), just like the C version I mentioned there.

Comment: @nnn Isn't that how NAudio works? Either way, another library may well be able to do it. And if not, it's not rocket science to do it yourself. :)

Comment: I doubt naudio works on SL. It uses lots of native interop and contains horrors such as WaveBuffer.

Comment: @bzlm, I guess I will implement the normalization using NAudio. I've never worked with sound, hope it is not rocket science to me :)

Comment: @CodeInChaos, You are right, at least I couldn't get it work on SL. I will do it on the server side.

Answer (score 1):

"Normalizing" audio files is generally not a great idea, since if there is just one sample at full volume, then it will have no effect. A better approach would be to run a [dynamic range compressor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_range_compression) on the audio.

In [Skype Voice Changer](http://skypefx.codeplex.com/) I have written sample code that uses [NAudio](http://naudio.codeplex.com) and passes audio through dynamic range compressors. However, as others have said, NAudio isn't directly usable in Silverlight due to interop. But you should be able to copy WaveFileReader, WaveFormat and WaveFileWriter out and compile them without needing to make too many code changes. Also, you won't be able to use the WaveBuffer mechanism for casting between arrays of bytes and shorts/floats, so you need to do the conversion the slow way (e.g. using [BitConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.aspx)).

Comment: Thanks. It helps. I will look into the "Dynamic range compressor" and "Skype Voice Changer"

Answer (score 0):

Some ideas (aside of trying [NAudio](http://naudio.codeplex.com/) or [Bass.NET](http://www.bass.net))

1. Call the compiled c executable
2. Compile it as a dll and use P/Invoke
3. Convert the C code to c#

Comment: Thanks for that. I considered these possibles but just wanted to see if there is a ready-to-use call which does the normalization work. I guess there isn't. And I will try to implement it using NAudio.